# Reuse cell... :(

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4, reusability

I have a table with 9 sections and 56 rows.

I want to add a text label for each cell. I created a `NSArray` `menuList` with 56 `NSDictionaries` and an array containing the number of rows in each section (`sectionsArray`).

Here is my code, but it doesn't work properly at all:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Use existing cell (reusable)
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

    //If no existing cell, create a new one
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //Define cell accessory type
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        //Create a subView for the cell
        CGRect subViewFrame = cell.contentView.frame;
        subViewFrame.origin.x += kInset;
        subViewFrame.size.width = kInset + kSelectLabelWidth;

        UILabel *selectedLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:subViewFrame];

        //SubView design
        selectedLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        selectedLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        selectedLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:selectedLabel];

        int indRow = 0;
        for (int i =0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
            indRow += [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        }
        indRow += indexPath.row;

        NSDictionary *cellText = [menuList objectAtIndex:indRow];

        selectedLabel.text = [cellText objectForKey:@"selection"];
        [selectedLabel release];

    }
    return cell;        
}
```

What's wrong in this code?

In `iOSSimulator`, i see that cell's text change sometimes when I'm scrolling, and labels are not in the right order.

Answer (score 6):

All the code that fills in your cells is with in the:

```
if (cell == nil) {
```

statement, so you end up creating a small number of cells and filling them in (when cell==nil) and then just return the dequeued ones.

This is what it should be:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Use existing cell (reusable)
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

    //If no existing cell, create a new one
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //Define cell accessory type
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        //Create a subView for the cell
        CGRect subViewFrame = cell.contentView.frame;
        subViewFrame.origin.x += kInset;
        subViewFrame.size.width = kInset + kSelectLabelWidth;

        UILabel *selectedLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:subViewFrame];

        //SubView design
        selectedLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        selectedLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        selectedLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:selectedLabel];
    }
    // At this point cell whether it is a reused cell or a new one
    // cell points to the object we need to fill in.

    int indRow = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
        indRow += [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    }
    indRow += indexPath.row;

    NSDictionary *cellText = [menuList objectAtIndex:indRow];

    selectedLabel.text = [cellText objectForKey:@"selection"];
    [selectedLabel release];

    return cell;       
}
```

This is what the code is doing:

```
Try to get a reusable cell

If no reusable cell is available
{
    create a new cell
}

Fill in the values for the cell
```

So when a cell scrolls of the screen it is put into a reuse queue. When a cell is about to come onto the screen your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. Allocating a new cell is slower than reusing an existing one, so you first try to get a cell from the reuse queue, but if one is not available you create a new one. Then you fill in your values.

Comment: I'm new in iOS development, and i really didn't get what i have to do. Do I have to change something?? the "if (cell == nil) " ?? Thank you.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a bit more information. Hopefully it makes sense to you now.

Comment: Well "application is terminating" does not give me a lot to go on, but I am guessing then that you are indexing off the end of your arrays.

Comment: Here's a tutorial with downloadable, runnable code that shows how to write a `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It might be useful http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/09/using-uitableview/ -- I might be a bit biased though; I wrote it ;-)

Comment: @MosHa -- if this solved your question you should accept the answer. That way the question is marked as resolved. If you don't do that other answerers will waste time looking at the question before they realize it is resolved... and I don't get my 15 reputation points. No but seriously, the folks that answer questions here don't get paid so don't waste their time.